# Apache Lucene 5.5.3 - Searching a string ending with special character

Tags: lucene, special-characters

I'm using Apache Lucene 5.5.3. I'm using `org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer` in my code and using below code snippet to create index.

```
Document doc = new Document();

doc.add(new TextField("userName", getUserName(), Field.Store.YES));
```

Now if I search for a string 'ALL-' , then I'm not getting any search results but if I search for a string 'ALL-Categories', then I'm getting some search results.

The same thing is happening for a string with special characters '+' , '.', '!' etc.

Below is my search code:-

```
Directory directory = new RAMDirectory();
IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(directory);
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
Document document = new Document();
document.add(new TextField("body", ALL-THE  GLITTERS IS NOT GOLD, Field.Store.YES));

IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(directory, new IndexWriterConfig(buildAnalyzer()));
writer.addDocument(document);
writer.commit();

Builder builder = new BooleanQuery.Builder();

Query query1 = new QueryParser(IndexAttribute.USER_NAME, buildAnalyzer()).parse(searchQUery+"*");
Query query2 = new QueryParser(IndexAttribute.IS_VETERAN, buildAnalyzer()).parse(""+isVeteran);
builder.add(query1, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
builder.add(query2, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

Query q = builder.build();

TopDocs docs = searcher.search(q, 10);
ScoreDoc[] hits = docs.scoreDocs;

private static Analyzer buildAnalyzer() throws IOException {
    return CustomAnalyzer.builder().withTokenizer("whitespace").addTokenFilter("lowercase")
            .addTokenFilter("standard").build();
}
```

So, Please suggest me on this.

Comment: So you have hypen in your String at the end? What was indexed value? Show your search code too.

Comment: Yes, I've a special character at the end. My indexed value is 'ALL-THE  GLITTERS IS NOT GOLD'.

Comment: You need to show value of `q.toString()`  for unsuccessful search result & also specify values of  variables - `searchQUery` & `isVeteran`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution with WildcardQuery, StringField and MultiFieldQueryParser combination. In addition to these classes, we have to do is escape the space in the query string

Answer (score 0):

Please refer section [Escaping Special Characters](http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_3/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Escaping_Special_Characters) to know special characters in Lucene 5.5.3.

As suggested in above article, you need to place a `\` or alternatively you can use method  `public static String escape(String s)` of `QueryParser` class to achieve the same.

Comment: Thanks Sabir for the reply. I tried it but it was not working as expected. I got the solution with WildcardQuery, StringField and MultiFieldQueryParser combination. In addition to these classes, we have to do is escape the space in the query string.